# Flutter | run my app as ios only from the ui prespective

Tags: flutter, dart

I just want to run my app built in xcode, but just as if the platform is ios to see the ui.
is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could comment out the code that you do not want and run it for ios

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).